# Bug with iPhone Navigation Bar button item (UIButtonBarItem)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I created a single view project in xcode 4.  I added a navigation bar item object. In that I added a navigation bar button called "Done".  All using he Xcode drag and drop. To that button I attached a very simple IBAction

```
- (IBAction) newContactDoneBtn:(id)sender
{  
    NSLog(@"INSIDE newContactDoneBtn");
}
```

In the "sent actions" I connected that Done button with this newContactDoneBtn IBAction. So far so good. If I compile and run it works fine i.e. I see the message log.

Now here's the kicker, if to that Done button I attach a modal storyboard i.e. when the user clicks on that Done button it takes them to another view controller ... my custom IBaction "newContactDoneBtn" never gets called and I see the new screen. Now why would that be?

An easy example to visualize all this would be the "Done" button in iphone contacts app.  When you click on adding a new contact there is the done button up there, you enter something in the fields and hit done, it takes you to another view controller and it did add that new contact to the address book.

It maybe a limitation of UIBarButtonItem but can anyone tell me if I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the segue to the button presumably overrides any action you had applied to it. Is the action still connected in interface builder after you've set the segue?

Why would you want both things to happen? What order should they be done in if you *were* able to fire an action and a segue simultaneously?

If you just want to call the modal view controller, then connecting the segue does that for you without needing to write any code. You can run anything you need in the `prepareForSegue:` method of your view controller. Alternatively, you can manually present the modal controller from your action method.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do it with prepareForSegue: action in my custom button IBAction.

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted by clicking the empty checkmark. This helps others to know that you are no longer looking for help on this issue.

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem with Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.0. I want to do some UI updating (start loading indicator animation in my IBAction when clicking the UIBarButtonItem), so I have to separate the IBAction with the code in prepareForSegue, otherwise, there seems no chance to show the loading indicator in the UI. And I expect the IBAction to be executed before prepareForSegue because prepareForSegue will make the transition to another UI view controller. However, it doesn't work at all and the IBAction won't execute if there is segue attached to the button. And it seems to me an iOS bug.